# How do I Use pool for my saving json object in to mysql database?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

I am working on program in which json is converted into mysql database,but I want to use multiprocessing pool for it, but since I am new to this I dont know how to use multithreading or multiprocessing. Please Help me out!

Thats my json names as result.json:

```
{
"contactlist": [{
    "name": "Anand Pixelstat Jio",
    "number": "+918709713497"
}, {
    "name": "Kishor Katkade",
    "number": "+918483909796"
}],
"id": "hello1285"
}
```

thats my code:

```
import pymysql
import json
from multiprocessing import Pool




mydb = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root'....)
cursor = mydb.cursor()

f = open("result.json")
datajson=json.load(f)

query = """INSERT INTO leader_contactlist(leader_id, name, contact_number) VALUES  (%s,%s,%s)"""
for ord in datajson["contactlist"]:
    #print(ord)
    a = (datajson["id"]) 
    #print(a)
    b = ((ord["name"]))
    #print(b)
    c =  (ord["number"])
    #print(c)

def hey():
    values = (a,b,c)
    cursor.execute(query,values)
    cursor.close()
    mydb.commit()
    mydb.close()

hey()

def main():
    p = Pool(processes = 4)
    r = p.map(hey)

main()
```

Comment: The fact your data come from a json file is totally irrelevant.

Comment: its may be because of four spaces..

Comment: can u help me? @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: No one??????????